# Mapview touch is not getting detected in ios

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitouch

I have a mapview in my xib.

```
-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    NSLog(@"Touch Description %@",[[touch view]description]);
    if ([touch view]  == self.mapView) 
   {
      //rest of my code
   }
}
```

The description that I get is

> MKAnnotationContainerView: 0x19057360; frame = (0 0; 4096 4096); autoresizesSubviews = NO; layer = CALayer: 0x1900df20

The if Loop is not being executed. How can I solve this. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    -(void) touchesBegan :(NSSet *) touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {
        UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
        NSLog(@"%@",[[touch view]description]);
        if ([touch view]  == self.mapView) 
       {
           //rest of my code
       }

       [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event ];
    }
```

Comment: @Hemang Can you explain why this works and why the OP's doesn't? Thanks.

Comment: OP's forgot to call super class function `[super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];` that's why it couldn't detect touch!